# Is there something better than low light vision - namely an improved low-light vision of some type?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, races

Most races or monsters I've researched all have x2 for low light vision. So I'm wondering if there is an improved version, specifically meaning x3, x4 or greater. A single example is sufficient, though it would be useful to know which race or monster has the greatest range of vision.

Answers from any WotC deemed official 3.x source are accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, there is.

Looking in Monster Manual 1, there are two examples of such an ability, both of which are named the same: **Superior Low-Light Vision**.

The Aquatic Elf race (x4), and the Giant Owl (x5).

A quick glance through other monster manuals turns up more.

---

As [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/203710/30200) indicates the Dark Creature template grants a Superior Low Light Vision ability.

...and...

The epic feat Improved Low Light Vision doubles the range.

Answer (score 2):

I feel it is also appropriate to point out the **Dark Creature** template as well as the **Improved Low-Light Vision** feat.

The **Dark Creature** template found in the **Tome of Magic** book (rules to create one are on page 161) grants any creature it is applied to **Superior Low-Light Vision**, though it does not note the multiplier so you'd need to refer to the sidebar on page 158 for the implied default which states that creatures with it see using four times the normal lighting radius, increasing both bright and shadowy illumination levels.

The **Improved Low-Light Vision** feat is an Epic feat found in the 3.0 **Epic Level Handbook** on page 58.  It requires **Low-Light Vision** (so by RAW **Superior Low-Light Vision** might not count) and doubles the range of your **Low-Light Vision**.  It can be taken multiple times increasing the range by one increment each time in an additive manner.  Due to it being an Epic feat it can only be taken by characters beyond level 20 unfortunately, but it's still worth mentioning.

Comment: Appreciate your finds!